# What is the best practice to communicate between a Rust program and an embedded WebAssembly runtime?

Tags: types, rust, scripting, communication, webassembly

I'm working on a Rust program that I want to, at runtime, use WebAssembly as a scripting language to drive its behavior. We'll assume the scripts are also written in Rust. I've read the tutorials for Wasmer, Wasmtime and Lucet, and while exported/imported functions can take as arguments and return WASM primitive types, there seems to be no easy/painless solution for passing arbitrary data between a Rust binary and a WASM script running within it. Strings, in particular, have to be handled by [manually passing a primitive  as a sort of pointer](https://medium.com/wasmer/executing-webassembly-in-your-rust-application-d5cd32e8ce46) to the runtime's linear memory and a length.

`wasm-bindgen` seems like it would be able to solve my problem, but it only targets WASM-JS communication in the browser. There are `*-interface-types` crates for Wasmer and Wasmtime, but they don't have tutorials and are experimental and subject to change. I don't need to pass `struct`s, but I would like to achieve something like this:

```rust
// in the host program
let argument: &[u8] = &[0, 1... n]; // dumb byte slice
let guest_result: Vec<u8> = wasm_runtime.call("guest_function", &[argument]);
// in the guest WASM library/script
let data_from_host: Vec<u8> = imported_function(some_other_bytes);
```

Just passing and returning `Vec<u8>`s or `&[u8]`s both ways would be enough, I could deserialize them with `bincode` or otherwise. Has anyone achieved this yet? I could share linear memory like with strings, but that seems unsafe, particularly with multiple scripts on multiple threads.

tl;dr I want to use WASM as scripting language and talk to it with `&[u8]` or `Vec<u8>`, haven't found any easy way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

This usability issue is known and it seems like it's being actively worked on: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/08/webassembly-interface-types/

Here is a followup to some of the closing notes in that post: https://github.com/bytecodealliance/wasmtime/issues/677

I have very little experience writing C or dealing with a syscall interface, so it was cumbersome for me to pass values around as well. For the most part I just invested time in building out higher level abstractions (like wasm-bindgen has done) so that i'd have an easier time passing data around.

As an example, it looks like wasi provides an interface you can implement, and they abstract away all the fiddly bits: https://docs.rs/crate/wasi/0.9.0+wasi-snapshot-preview1/source/src/lib_generated.rs you can see lucet implementing it here: https://github.com/bytecodealliance/lucet/blob/master/lucet-wasi/src/runtime.rs

I don't think that'll help you much unless you're trying to implement wasi, but it's a good example of implementing the kind of abstractions you're going for.